# array with json objects needs to be sorted

Tags: json, swift

json data is returned from a dataTask network call and assigned to an array here:

```
   let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
      if let jsonarray = json as? [Any] {
        self.cardArray = jsonarray
     }
```

the json looks like this:

```
[ 
  {
    "deviceID":114,
    "UserName":"freds@hotmail.com",
    "Name":"under sink",
    "UniqueId":"D0:B5:C2:F2:B8:88",
    "RowCreatedDateTime":"2018-01-02T16:07:31.607"
  }
]
```

how can I sort(descending) this array based on the json property called RowCreatedDateTime?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
cardArray.sort{
    $0.RowCreatedDateTime < $1.RowCreatedDateTime
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all dictionaries contain the key `RowCreatedDateTime` you have to get the values by key. You cannot use dot notation with a dictionary.

```
cardArray.sort{
    ($0["RowCreatedDateTime"] as! String) < $1["RowCreatedDateTime"] as! String
}
```

And if you know that the type of the array is `[[String:Any]]` never cast it to much more unspecified `[Any]`.

---

Declare `cardArray` as array of dictionaries

```
var cardArray = [[String:Any]]()
```

and parse the JSON this way

```
do {
    if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
        self.cardArray = jsonArray
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Consider to use `Codable` in Swift 4 to parse the JSON into structs. That makes things much easier.

Comment: im getting a error messsage: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: you will have to give me baby steps here, because i am new to swift... so do you mean your solution wont work?

Comment: btw, what is the difference between cardArray1 = [[String:Any]]() and cardArray1: [Any] = []    (notice one defined as String:Any and the other one, just Any)

Comment: `[[String:Any]]` tells the compiler the object is an array of dictionaries, so the compiler knows the subscription type. If you declare `[Any]` you'll get the *has no subscript members* error, because the compiler does **not** know what the array actually contains. Be always as specific as possible to help the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Make `cardArray` `[[String:Any]]` instead of `[Any]`.

```
var cardArray = [[String:Any]]()
```

Then

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
if let jsonarray = json as? [[String:Any]] {
    self.cardArray = jsonarray
} else {
    self.cardArray = []
}
```

Finally

```
self.cardArray.sort {
    guard let left = $0["RowCreatedDateTime"] as? String else { return true }
    guard let right = $1["RowCreatedDateTime"] as? String else { return false }

    return left < right
}
```